# Gradle build for Java is taking huge amount of time to complete when executing gradle clean build from mac terminal

Tags: java, macos, gradle, intellij-idea, terminal

When trying to execute the command `gradle clean build` from my mac terminal it takes around **1.5 hours** to complete successfully.

I've the following gradle versionon my mac:

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.7 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.0 x86_64
```

I also have the `gradle.properties` file in my gradle home with the following contents:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8192m
# org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
# org.gradle.configuration-cache=true
# org.gradle.caching=true
```

I've commented caching part as the build fails when executing from the terminal.

Whereas when building the project from intellij ide by using the option `build project` it takes **4 mins** to complete.
I've a `gradle-wrapper.properties` in the project folder with the following contents:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Is there any difference in the execution of those builds?

How can I reduce the build time from my terminal as it hampers productivity?

Can anyone help in this regard?
Thanks

Comment: Is cache disabled in MAC?

Comment: enabled it but same result

Comment: Might be worth running gradle clean build --info to try and see which exact step of the process takes the longest and go from there. How long does gradlew clean build takes to run from the console?